# Java - force/warns deprecated annotation without link (or deprecated link)

Tags: java, deprecated, deprecation-warning

I see that using [deprecation annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/deprecation/deprecation.html#what) isn't forcing/warning if user doesn't add link to the new item:

> The ability to deprecate a class, method, or member field solves the problem. Java supports two mechanisms for deprecation: and an annotation, (supported starting with J2SE 5.0) and a Javadoc tag (supported since 1.1). Existing calls to the old API continue to work, but the annotation causes the compiler to issue a warning when it finds references to deprecated program elements. The Javadoc tag and associated comments warn users against using the deprecated item and **tell them what to use instead**

Also specify in [@deprecated oracle docs](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#@deprecated)

> The @deprecated description in the first sentence should at least tell the user when the API was deprecated **and what to use as a replacement.**

But the replacement isn't forced or warns about its absent

For example Apache's [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) doesn't specify replacement in several cases

> ```
> public static final String escapeJava(String input)
> ```
>
> **Deprecated.**
>
> Escapes the characters in a String using Java String rules....

Or direct to other deprecated methods

> ```
> public static final String escapeXml(String input)
> ```
>
> **Deprecated.**
>
> use escapeXml10(java.lang.String) or escapeXml11(java.lang.String) instead.

Is there any way/tool that can warns if it doesn't state what is my (valid) substitute solution for deprecated method/class?

**Side note**: docs also offer how to ignore a missing replacement:

> If the member has no replacement, the argument to @deprecated should be "No replacement".

Comment: Are the methods on `StringEscapeUtils` actually specifying they are deprecated, or are they just inheriting the annotation from the class (where the alternative is stated).

Comment: @AndyTurner It's not consistent, I see for example `@Deprecated  public static final String escapeXml(String input) {`

Comment: I suspect that is historical: it looks like the method was deprecated in favour of the other methods in the same class; then the class was deprecated after.

Comment: @AndyTurner it's just an example of missing link to a new item on deprecated method. Can I create a warning (eclipse/sonar/...) in such cases?

Comment: other tools are available, but this could be achieved with Google's Error Prone. Interestingly, there is [a check for the other way round](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/DepAnn) (`@deprecated` in Javadoc, but no `@Deprecated` in the code). I can ask the team why it's not enforced both ways.

Comment: @AndyTurner just to verify, I'm asking about missing **replacement link** of deprecated method

Comment: there is no guarantee that there is a replacement for a method. You might simply be saying "don't use this, it's broken", for example `Thread.stop()`. Or there might be more than 1, as in the example here.